# Error while returning list

Tags: python

This is a code for finding sum of factors of a number. The list returned in the find factors function is i guess not accessible to the sum function because when I am printing the list it is giving the correct list.

The error that I receive is : TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

```
def perfect_number(n):
    def sum(list,counter,value):
        if counter==len(list):
            print (value)
        else:
            sum(list,counter+1,value+list[counter])
    def find_factors(n,a,list):
        if (a==n):
                        print (list,len(list))
            return (list)
        elif (n%a )== 0:
            list.append(a)                      
            find_factors(n,a+1,list)
        elif (n%a) !=0:
            find_factors(n,a+1,list)
    xyz = find_factors(n,1,[])
    return sum(xyz,0,0)



perfect_number(6)
```

Comment: first of all, don't use builtins as variable/function names

Comment: but still,whats the error??

Comment: Well, `find_factors` does not return anything, thus `xyz` is `None`.

Comment: but why is it not returning the list?? when i have used return list command!

Comment: You return it only in one of the inner recursive calls, but it is not propagated to the outermost call. Try to add return before all the recursive calls to `find_factors`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some return statements:

```
def is_perfect_number(n):
    def sum_recursive(factors,counter,value):
        if counter==len(factors):
            return value
        else:
            return sum_recursive(factors, counter+1, value+factors[counter])

    def find_factors(n,a,factors):
        if (a==n):
            return
        elif (n%a) == 0:
            factors.append(a)                      
            find_factors(n,a+1,factors)
        elif (n%a) !=0:
            find_factors(n,a+1,factors)

    xyz = []
    find_factors(n, 1, xyz)
    return sum_recursive(xyz,0,0)==n

print is_perfect_number(6)
print is_perfect_number(28)
print is_perfect_number(228)
```

Comment: Should probably also be `return sum_recursive(xyz,0,0) == n` to complete the test.

Comment: I'll match the function too.

Comment: Thanx man! But why do we have to use so many return statements? I just want to return only in the if condition.

Comment: I see you have converted this from a functional programming style. In most functional languages the return statement is implicit.

Comment: I think I understand better how the algorithm is meant to work now.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, you're right. I've added +1 back :)